# Setting NTAuthenticationProviders at an Application level in IIS 6

Tags: iis

I have the following structure in IIS.

```
Internet Information Services  
 (local computer)
  Web Sites  
   Default Web Site  
    MyApplication
```

`MyApplication` is a Application in IIS.

Integrated Windows authentication is NOT set on the `Default Web Site`.
However I want to set Integrated Windows authentication on `MyApplication`. (Its an intranet app).

This can be done via the GUI: Right click on the `Default Web Site` and choose `Properties`. Select the `Directory Security` tab, and click `Edit` on the Anonymous access and authentication control.

I want to include this in a setup script. I have other setup commands, using `adsutil.vbs` but I'm struggling to set up the Integrated windows authentication.

Running:

> cscript //nologo c:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs GET /W3SVC/1/NTAuthenticationProviders

Returns

```
NTAuthenticationProviders       : (STRING) "NTLM"
```

However, i exepcted to be able to run

> cscript //nologo c:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs GET /W3SVC/1/ROOT/MyApplication/NTAuthenticationProviders

But this returns

```
Error Trying To GET the property: (Get Method Failed)
NTAuthenticationProviders (This property is probably not allowed at this node)
```

Is it not possible to set `NTAuthenticationProviders` Metabase property on an appliction level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The metabase property that controls the Authenticated Access property values on the IIS Directory Security -> Authentication Methods dialogue is actually called `AuthFlags`.

The value is a flag and is documented here:

> [AuthFlags Metabase Property (IIS 6.0) (TechNet)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6cc53bc1-6487-412c-ae93-063cd86b4f6e.mspx?mfr=true)

To set this value to Integrated Windows Authentication (`AuthNTLM`) use the following command (*take care because this command operates on the Default Website, IISNumber:1*) -

> `adsutil.vbs SET /W3SVC/1/ROOT/MyApplication/AuthFlags 4`

If you want to set, say, both NTLM and Basic authentication then you would boolean OR the values together, e.g. `MD_AUTH_BASIC | AuthNTLM`. This would product an integer result of `6`:

> `:: Set both NTLM and Basic authentication`
>   `adsutil.vbs SET /W3SVC/1/ROOT/MyApplication/AuthFlags 6`

If you inspect the metabase file (`C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\MetaBase.xml`) and search for:

> `Location="/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/MyApplication"`

...you will see the attribute that controls this setting (after setting to 6 as above):

> `AuthFlags="AuthBasic | AuthNTLM"`

It may take some time before this value updates in the metabase because changes such as this aren't immediately flushed to the file (although IISRESET will cause it to update immediately).