# How to set Authentication Methods in IIS programmatically

Tags: windows, iis, authentication, wsh

We are working on automating the deployment of some IIS applications.  I've used cscript.exe inside a windows batch file to create the web app and such.  There are however a few settings currently done by hand that I need to automate.  Namely, if you look at the properties of an app, under Directory Structure -> Authentication and access control -> Edit, I need to uncheck Enable anonymous access and check Integrated Windows authentication.

Is there an easy way to do this from a windows batch file?

EDIT: I should clarify this is IIS 6.0, so appcmd is not available.

Comment: You might look into using Windows PowerShell for this type of task in the future. Although the syntax is clunky, it allows access to .NET classes, etc and is significantly more powerful than vbscript or batch files.

Comment: What exactly do you do in the script you run by cscript.exe. Do you create the site in this script? Or do you use `IIsWeb.vbs` in the batch file?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a sample cscript snippet.

Comment: I basically copy the web site tree under Inetpub/wwwroot and then use:  "" cscript.exe %systemroot%\system32\iisweb.vbs /create c:\inetpub\wwwroot "%1" /b %2 ""  where %1 and %2 are some vars for the app name. If I then go into IIS Manager, under Web Sites, I can see the site and its identifier (under the Default Web Site and Sharepoint Admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a very similar question a wee while back. The example uses the `asdutil.vbs` tool which you can call from your batch file:

> [Setting NTAuthenticationProviders at an Application level in IIS 6 (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571609/setting-ntauthenticationproviders-at-an-application-level-in-iis-6/1576017#1576017)

**Updated:**

Because you've already got a *CScript* script to create the website, you can just set the `AuthFlags` in the script:

```
'' Some values just as an example
iisNumber = 668
ipAddress = "172.16.3.200"
hostName = "myserver.com"
wwwfolder = "c:\mysites\www"


Dim serverBindings(1)
serverBindings(0) = ipAddress & ":80:www." & hostName
serverBindings(1) = ipAddress & ":80:" & hostName


'' Create server
Set w3svc = GetObject("IIS://localhost/w3svc")
Set newWebServer = w3svc.Create("IIsWebServer", iisNumber)
newWebServer.ServerBindings = serverBindings
newWebServer.ServerComment = "Server is: " & hostName
newWebServer.SetInfo

'' Create /root app
Set rootApp = newWebServer.Create("IIsWebVirtualDir", "ROOT")
rootApp.Path = wwwFolder
rootApp.AccessRead = true
rootApp.AccessScript = true
rootApp.AppCreate(True)
rootApp.AuthFlags = 4 '' <== Set AuthFlags here
rootApp.SetInfo
```

Comment: Very useful, but one question, the script you provided works on the defaults web app (1) as you pointed out.  How do I know from a programmatic standpoint, the Application ID, for an app other than the default app?  I know its name, but windows generates the ID.

Answer (score 2):

hope this helpes:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1159665.aspx

Comment: I guess I would ask the same question I asked of Kev. This command from the link works as advertised:

adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/root/Authflags 4

However I want to run this command as part of the installation of a new app.  The app as installed currently has an Identifier of 208223887, so I would want:

adsutil.vbs set w3svc/208223887/root/Authflags 4

but I don't know that value until the app is installed.  Is there any way to get this as a variable after the install step so I can substitute it into this command further down in my script?

Answer (score 1):

See [Configure Windows Authentication (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(WS.10).aspx):

```
appcmd set config /section:windowsAuthentication /enabled:true | false
```

For IIS 6 probably WMI is the alternative:

- [Creating Sites and Virtual Directories, and Setting Properties Using WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524913.aspx)
- [IIsWebServiceSetting (WMI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524328.aspx)
- [AuthFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524513.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sSitePath = "1" 'Set the site ID here
Set oSite =  GetObject("IIS://localhost/" & sSitePath & "/root")

Select Case oSite.AuthFlags
  Case 1
    Wscript.Echo "Anonymous"
  Case 2
    Wscript.Echo "Basic"
  Case 4
    Wscript.Echo "NTLM"
  Case 6
    Wscript.Echo "MD5"
  Case 64
    Wscript.Echo "Passport"
End Select
```