# check iis authentication settings with vbscript

Tags: list, iis, authentication, vbscript

Is there a way to check what type of authentication (anonymous, ntlm..) is configured in a
website using a vbscript?
and if is it possible it work on any version of iis?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there no single way to achieve this on any version of IIS. Methods of accessing this information on various versions of IIS are discussed in answers to this question:
[How to set Authentication Methods in IIS programattically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862071/how-to-set-authentication-methods-in-iis-programattically).